# How to specify a QList<int> type as signal/slot argument type with pyside/pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6

My question is for pyside6, but since it may be relevant for other, I ask also for pyqt...

With pyside, you declare a slot like this :

```
@Slot(argtypes...)
def slot_name(self, args:type...):
  ...
```

With simple types, it's straightforward... But how to specify an arguent type `QList<int>` (or `list[int]`) ? (spoiler alert : pyside does not know about python type hinting system...).

Comment: Do you *really* require the decorator?

Comment: Use a string: `@Slot('QList<int>')`.